# Display Array Items in a Table with PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form which uploads a text.txt file with action="profit-process.php"

In profit-process.php I convert the .txt file into an array:

```
<?php
$file = "text.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); // Make all conditions to avoid errors
$read = file_get_contents($file); //read
$lines = explode("\n", $read);//get
foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    $code[] =  $value[0];
    $name[] = $value[1];
    $cost[] = $value[2];
    $selling_price[] = $value[3];
  }
echo "<pre>";
print_r($lines); //explore results
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

What I would like to do is display the data in .txt (which goes into the array) with a table instead of print_r($lines).

So the goal formatting would be:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>cost</th><th>Selling Price</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1234</td><td>Nike Air</td><td>30.00</td><td>60.00</td></tr>
</table>
```

There will be multiple rows of text file therefore the number of rows in the table will reflect the text file data.

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you show a few lines in the text file?  On average, how many lines are there in a text file?

Comment: 0227 Item 1 34.65 89.99 
0226 Item 2 34.65 89.99 
0225 Item 3 34.65 89.99 
0224 Item 4 34.65 89.99

Comment: Is the format of the text file specified or can you change it?  For example can it be changed to CSV?

Comment: It starts off life as a xls.  So I could save it as a csv instead of a .txt which would actually be easier!  Not sure how I'd read in the csv

Comment: I had a hunch it was inventory files you're importing, exporting it to CSV will make your life *a lot* easier.  You have `fgetcsv`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: I've got a sneaky suspicion that the problem is with this line: $lines = explode("\n", $read);//get  ?

Comment: If you want to continue with your method, you'll need to extract each element in the line, for example by using a regex like this: `'/(\d{1,4}) (.*) ([0-9]*\.[0-9]*) ([0-9]*\.[0-9]*)/'`.  I do **not** recommend you go down that path if you can export to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Your final program should be:

Note: read [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) first.

```
<?php
$file = "text.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
$handle = fopen($file, "r"); // Make all conditions to avoid errors
$read = file_get_contents($file); //read
$lines = explode("\n", $read);//get

$arr = array();
foreach($lines as $key => $value){
    $temp = array();
    $temp['code'] =  $value[0];
    $temp['name'] =  $value[1];
    $temp['cost'] =  $value[2];
    $temp['selling_price'] =  $value[3];
  $arr[] = $temp;
 }
echo "<pre>";
print_r($lines); //explore results
echo "</pre>";
?>
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Selling Price</th>
    </tr>
<?php
if (! empty($arr)) {
    foreach ($arr as $elem) {
        extract($elem); // EXTRACT VARIABLES SO THAT, $elem['cost'] becomes $cost, read PHP documentation on extract();
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $code;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cost;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $selling_price;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Programming Student, this is displaying a table, however the data in the first item in the array (code)is getting place accross cells.  So for example if the code was 12345, then in Code I have 1, in Name I have 2, in Cost I have 3, in Selling Price I have 4!!

Comment: Here is an example of the text:  0227 Item 1 34.65 89.99 
0226 Item 2 34.65 89.99 
0225 Item 3 34.65 89.99 
0224 Item 4 34.65 89.99

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>cost</th><th>Selling Price</th></tr>
  <?php
  foreach($lines as $key => $value) {
  ?>
  <tr><td><?php echo $value[0]?></td><td><?php echo $value[1]?></td><td><?php echo $value[2]?></td><td><?php echo $value[3]?></td></tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>cost</th><th>Selling Price</th></tr>
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($code);$i++):?>
  <tr><td><?php echo $code[$i];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $name[$i];?></td>
<td><?php echo $cost[$i];?></td>
<td><?php echo $selling_price[$i];?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```